# Appending multiple values to one key in an empty hash

Tags: ruby, string, hash

I'm trying to find the string in an array that has the most matches to dictionary words in a file. I store the score (matches) as the key of a hash and the corresponding matching strings as the value to the key. For example:

- The string `"XXBUTTYATCATYSSX"` has three substring word matches. The score for this string would be `3`. The string and score are stored in the `scores` hash as:

  ```
  scores = { 3 => "XXBUTTYATCATYSSX" }
  ```
- The string `"YOUKKYUHISJFXPOP"` also has three matches. This should be stored in the hash as:

  ```
  scores = { 3 => "XXBUTTYATCATYSSX", "YOUKKYUHISJFXPOP" }
  ```

"

```
scores = { }
#scores = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }
File.open("#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/dictionary.txt","r") do |file|
  #going to a string in the array
  strArray.each_index do |str|
    score = 0
    match = strArray[str]
    #going to a line in the dictionary file
    file.each_line do |line|
      dictWord = line.strip!.upcase
      if match.include? dictWord
        score += 1
      end
    end
    #the key in the scores hash equals the score (amount of matches)
    #the values in the scores hash are the matched strings that have the score of the key
    #scores[score] << match
    scores.merge!("#{score}" => match)
end
```

edit:
I've revised the code above. Now it will not enter into `file.each_line do |line|` after the first loop

Please help.

Comment: What is ptArray ? Did you define it previously on the code?

Comment: ptArray, is the array with strings in it. I did define it, this is just the snippet of code I'm having issues with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `File` objects, you can't read them twice. That is, if you read the entire file once with `each_line`, then you try to do it again, the second time won't do anything because it was already at the end of the file. To read the file again, you need to rewind it with `file.rewind` before you try to read from it.

The second problem is that you're trying to add to an array that doesn't exist. For example:

```
scores = {}
scores[3] #=> nil
scores[3] << 'ASDASDASD' # crashes (can't use << with nil)
```

You need to create an array for each score before you can add words to it. One way to do this would be to check if the key exists before using it, like this:

```
scores = {}
if scores[3].nil?
  scores[3] = []
end
scores[3] << 'word' # this will work
```

Answer (score 0):

Straight to the code:

```
scores = Hash.new

File.open("#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/dictionary.txt","r") do |file|
  strings.each do |string|
    score = 0
    file.each do |line|
      score += 1 if string.match(line.strip!.upcase)
    end
    # store score and new array unless it already have same score
    scores.store(score, []) unless scores.has_key?(score)
    scores[score] << string
    # rewind to read dictionary from first line on next iteration
    file.rewind
  end
end
```

`strings` is your array of strings to compare with dict:

e.g. `strings = ["XXBUTTYYOUATCATYSSX", "YOUKKYUHISJFXPOP"]`)